# Moving lights or scene objects in Unity seems to cause a second point light to shrink or dim

Tags: unity, lighting

[image: Animation showing light changing in size/brightness as other objects are moved]

Moving a Point Light in 2d space seems to be dimming lights around it. What is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you using post processing effects like the Post processing stack?

Comment: No nothing i m just starting up

Comment: After setting up a 2D scene with multiple point lights, I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. The lights don't show any change in size or brightness as I move them around. Have you been able to recreate this effect in a new, empty project?

Comment: @DMGregory yes like it's my 3rd time

Comment: @DMGregory can u send your project file

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is caused by the rendering path you are currently using. In the forward rendering path there are only a limited amount of pixel lights allowed, where in deferred all of the lighting is done per-pixel.
I recommend reading the references here: [deferred](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-DeferredLighting.html) and [forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-ForwardRendering.html) rendering.
This will explain the issue that you were describing:
In Forward Rendering, some number of brightest lights that affect each object are rendered in fully per-pixel lit mode. Then, up to 4 point lights are calculated per-vertex. The other lights are computed as Spherical Harmonics (SH), which is much faster but is only an approximation.
Unfortunately, the deferred pipeline is not currently supported on mobile, so you will need to use forward and SH lighting for dynamic lighting.
You may want to consider using a feature such as light probes in conjunction with light mapping to get better quality lighting at less cost if that is an option.
Hope it helps